# Best way to handle checkbox in Laravel4?

Tags: checkbox, laravel, laravel-4

I'm starting to work with Laravel4, I was struggling with some basic stuff like this one below. There's any other way to handle the value for an unmarked checkbox than adding a hidden checkbox for the default value like below?

```
<td class="text-center">
    {{Form::hidden('status', 0)}}
    {{Form::checkbox('status')}}
</td>
```

This is working fine for me right now, but I would like to know if there's any better way like handling the value in the Controller@update.

EDIT: The values of the checkbox on the form are being handle by Input::all() at the Update action.

Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

This is default behavior of HTML actually, not related to how Laravel handle inputs. From [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#checkbox):

> When a form is submitted, only "on" checkbox controls can become successful.
>
> ...
>
> Every successful control has its control name paired with its current value as part of the submitted form data set.

So, a more generic approach would be not to change your HTML form, but change the behavior when you are retrieving the input, e.g.:

```
$status = Input::get('status', false);
```

Comment: What if you are doing a: $input = array_except(Input::all(), '_method'); in order to get the form values and send this values to the update, there's any way to get ALL the values from the input but setting some default values in case the values doesn't exists?

Comment: Ah, that's a good question. Most probably beyond my knowledge, since I never came across a situation I needed that (I always avoid mass assignment). It's worth mentioning what you just said in the original question though.

Comment: Thanks, also your quote about the HTML Specs help me with something else.

Answer (score 0):

In the FormBuilder class, the checkbox method has these parameters.

```
checkbox(string $name, mixed $value = 1, bool $checked = null, array $options = array())
```

So you want:

```
Form::checkbox('status', 0, false, ['class' => 'form-control'])
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What happens here is what @Unnawut mention below: When a form is submitted, only "on" checkbox controls can become successful.
So if I set the Checkbox as you mention and is not selected, even when having a default value, the checkbox is not listed in the Input::all array.

Comment: Oh true, in that case, what Unnawut answered below would be the correct answer. Input::get('status', false);